# How do I copy file contents to a variable while using sudo?

Tags: bash, sudo, bash-scripting

I have a file that only has root permissions.  I need to copy its contents into a variable in my script, but when I do `content=$(sudo cat secretfile.txt)` it captures the "last login" information as well as the file content!  I'm pretty sure there's a way to turn that off, but I don't want to change the system settings, I just want a way to capture only the file content.  What's the best way to do this?

Comment: You're right, I just checked and it was content=$(sudo cat secretfile.txt). Then if I do `echo $content` I get [file content] Last login: Thu Apr 15...

Comment: Does `Last login: …` appear when you do e.g. `content=$(sudo cat your_own_file.txt)` with `your_own_file.txt` being empty or anything but `Last login: …`? My point is: how do you know `Last login: …` is not in the `secretfile.txt`?

Comment: Well I know for sure it's not in the secret file because I also have root access.  But also, yes, if I do sudo cat on a file I own, I get the login message.

Comment: Please state this fact in the question body.

Comment: What is the output of `type -a sudo`? What is the content of `/etc/pam.d/sudo`? What is the output of `grep -rl lastlog /etc/pam.d/`? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] the question and put information there.